# vue.js img how to display from random API

Tags: vue.js

My array of workers

```js
export const workers = [
    {
        uuid:"07f67e76-9154-4f0a-99a0-a34d23fe7dd7",
        first_name:"Karolina", 
        last_name:"Water",
         email:"Karolina.water@gmail.com",
          img:"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/94.jpg",
     },
],
```

My component as below,

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="{{worker.img}}" alt=""/>  How can i display this img in this place ? should i use fetch
    <p>{{worker.first_name}}</p>       
  </div>
</template>
<script src="../components/Developer/developer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the image URL to `src` on a `img` tag

Use fetch to get data

[Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuPGltZyBoZWlnaHQ9XCIyMDBcIiB3aWR0aD1cIjIwMFwiIHYtaWY9XCJ3b3JrZXJcIiA6c3JjPVwid29ya2VyLnJlc3VsdHNbMF0ucGljdHVyZS5sYXJnZVwiID5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQgfSBmcm9tIFwidnVlXCI7XG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQoe1xuICBkYXRhKCl7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIHtcbiAgICAgIHdvcmtlcjogdW5kZWZpbmVkXG4gICAgfVxuICB9LFxuICBtb3VudGVkKCl7XG4gICAgZmV0Y2goXCJodHRwczovL3JhbmRvbXVzZXIubWUvYXBpL1wiKS50aGVuKGRhdGEgPT4gZGF0YS5qc29uKCkpLnRoZW4oZGF0YSA9PiB0aGlzLndvcmtlciA9IGRhdGEpIFxuICB9XG59KTtcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuIn0=)

```js
<template>
<img height="200" width="200" v-if="worker" :src="worker.results[0].picture.large" >
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data(){
    return {
      worker: undefined
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/").then(data => data.json()).then(data => this.worker = data) 
  }
});
</script>
```